# C++ templates and friend declaration

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code. I'm guessing that I didn't overload `<<` correctly, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The below code implements a simple Stack container. It fails at `cout << si;`

**update:** Made suggested changes, still not compiling.

**update2:** Got it! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T = int, int N = 10>
struct Stack
{
    T elems[N];
    unsigned int size;

    Stack()
    {
        size=0;
    }

    void push(T e)
    {
        elems[size]=e;
        size++;
    }

    T pop()
    {
        size--;
        return elems[size];
    }

            template <typename T, int N>
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Stack<T, N> &stack);
};

template <typename T, int N>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Stack<T, N> &stack)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        os << stack.elems[i];
    }

    return os;
}


int main()
{   

    Stack<> si;
    si.push(3);
    cout << si;

}
```

Comment: What is is not doing as expected? Does it compile? Your question is rather vague...

Comment: What did you hope your code would do? What did it actually do? (Questions of the form "This didn't work; why?" are *always* improved by providing those two pieces of information.)

Comment: It's usually helpful to quote the exact compile error that you are receiving.

Comment: It's unhelpful to edit your code to make existing answers invalid. It makes your question hard to follow for people who read your question later. You now have a different error: the template arguments `T` and `N` in the friend declaration are shadowing the template arguments in the class template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T, int N>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Stack<T> &stack)
```

The problem with this template is that the parameter `N` cannot be inferred from either of the function arguments because you are using the default template argument for the `Stack` argument.

Looking at your implementation, you almost certainly didn't intend this as you use `N` as the loop bound whereas `Stack<T>` has 10 elements. You probably meant to write:

```
template <typename T, int N>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Stack<T, N> &stack)
```

Also, your friend declaration needs to match the template, at the moment the friend declaration is declaring a non-template friend overload.

This would declare an appropriate friend template.

```
template< typename S, int M >
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Stack<S, M> &stack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Stack<T,N> &stack);
//                                              ^^ -- note this
```

in both definition and declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully specify all template arguments for your stack here:

```
template <typename T, int N>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Stack<T, N> &stack);
```

other wise the compiler can't deduce the proper `N` for your overloaded streaming operator.

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answers, but may I suggest turning:

```
void push(T e)
```

into:

```
void push(const T& e)
```

for performance wise, since you have no idea what T will be, and passing it on the stack isnt a good idea.